# Google Maps not working in meteor android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, meteor

I'm trying to deploy a meteor app on android, which contains a google map in index.html:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApIkEy&libraries=places"></script>
```

In the web counterpart of the meteor app, the map appears correctly, and I deployed it to [galaxy](https://www.meteor.com/hosting).

In the mobile (android) version, when I test the app on an emulator, using

```
meteor run android
```

the map shows up correctly.

But when I connect it to my server, using

```
meteor run android --mobile-server https://myapp.meteorapp.com
```

I get the following error:

> "ReferenceError: google is not defined

...and the map doesn't appear.

So, apparently, when my mobile app connects to the server, the google map API doesn't work, but it does work when connected to the `localhost`.

Is this a CORS issue (note the `https://`)?

Comment: Have you checked if your API key is registered from the domain you are trying to access from?

Comment: @Coder My API key is currently unrestricted, it can be accessed from any domain

Comment: any API key that you get from Google is either specific to a domain or you can register your domain URL's in the google account you hold with them