# Google map doesn't load in meteor android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps, meteor

I have a meteor app which has a google map like so:

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        ...
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApIkEy&callback=initMap"></script>
```

When I run the app using `meteor run android`, the `initMap()` callback fires up correctly.

But when I run the app using `meteor run android --mobile-server http://localhost:3000`, it is never called.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks :)

Comment: A couple suggestions: Don't use Gmaps the traditional way, use this package https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps. Secondly your map may not work on an android device unless you use the SDK, Cordova could probably facilitate this.  Anytime you use a web API on a device, it probably will not work as expected unless you use the correct SDK.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign I solved it by adding the lines specified in the end of the module that you have specified, [here](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps#mobile-platforms), ie. by adding `App.accessRule('*.google.com/*'); App.accessRule('*.googleapis.com/*'); App.accessRule('*.gstatic.com/*');` in `mobile-config.js`. So, you can post this as an answer :) Thanks alot

Comment: @NicholasByDesign You can add this as an answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113262/google-maps-not-working-in-meteor-android) post too :)